# Download pdf file with incrementing filename

Tags: c#, batch-file, pdf, cmd, download

I need to download a pdf from the internet on a scheduled basis. Typically I would just use a command line task for this if possible but there is a twist. The file I need to download is not always the same name. It is a weekly publication that is published online. Basically the set up is this.

The file path for this week is

```
http://www.website.com/newsletter1of2014.pdf
```

next week it would be

http://www.website.com/newsletter2of2014.pdf

and so on and so forth.

So how can I set something up to download these files automatically, also resetting the first number to 1 once it reaches 52 and changing the year by one to 2015 etc?

I have some experience in c# programming and am not above writing a console application to do this task if necessary.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: So far I haven't gotten anything to work properly. I started a c# console application to download the file using WebClient.DownloadFile() but I could not figure out how to incrementally add to an integer value that persists between runs of the program. My plan was to write a console app that would be triggered by a windows scheduled task. it would form the download url based on two persistent integer values, issueNumber and issueYear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethings like

```
    const string BASE_URL ="http://www.website.com/";
    const string FILE_NAME = "newsletter{0}of{1}.pdf";

    var stringLastNumber = File.ReadAllText("lastnumber.txt");
    var lastNumber = Convert.ToInt32(stringLastNumber);

    var thisFileName = String.Format(FILE_NAME, lastNumber++, DateTime.Now.Year);
    var uri = new Uri(String.Concat(BASE_URL, thisFileName));

    File.WriteAllText("lastnumber.txt", lastNumber.ToString());

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(uri, thisFileName);
    }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I added an if statement cause the issue number resets each year.

Comment: Is there anyway to account for the possibility of a file not being there or there not being a connection to the internet?